# iPhone Emoji Decimal Value Representation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, decimal, emoji

I want to display an Emoji icon using it's decimal value, for example `&#xe41e`

How can I display it in an UILabel ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
textLabel.text = @"\ue41e";
```

Instead of &#x, use `\u`. I hope this is the one you want.

Comment: I have a little issue, I store the decimal values in a NSDictionary and retrieve them: [self.emojiOutput setText:[self.dict objectForKey:[self.key lowercaseString]]];


For some reason when I retrieve them from the dictionary the label displays the decimal value, thanks

Comment: Whether the `dict` contains the NSString value preceded by `\u`?