# How to insert Hebrew text into pdf?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to insert the text on PDF page. I tired this

```
 NSString *str = @"יככעימבבגיננימ";  //hebrew characters
 const char *cstr = [str UTF8String];
```

//draw the text on pdf page

```
 CGContextShowTextAtPoint(PDFPagecontext, 100, 100), cstr,strlen(cstr));
```

But on Pdf page it look like something else instead of what i tried to insert. Can any one tell me what is the right way to insert the text if that particular text contains any Hebrew text.

Thanks,

loganathan

Comment: Have you tried with unicode? Also, have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700292/iphone-emoji-decimal-value-representation/8700398#8700398) where the unicode text has been set to UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NSString Additions

```
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (ctx, kCGTextFill);  //ctx is CGContextRef
UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
[str drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100,100) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Times New Roman" size:10]]
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

It works for me.